# Microsoft Graph get delta changes in meeting room calendars

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to get changes on a calendar associated to a meeting room.

When I call first the calendarView/delta with the startDateTime and endDateTime, the response is ok and I have the events. 
My call is : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/meetingRoomId/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&endDateTime=2050-12-31T00:00:00.000Z

When I have the nextLink with the skipToken : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/meetingRoomId/calendar/calendarView/delta?$skiptoken=token
I have the followed error :

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "SyncStateNotFound",
    "message": "The sync state root folder is not found.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "5cab61d2-a254-485b-98ee-190130940307",
        "date": "2018-04-19T12:56:51"
    }
}
}
```

I have this error from the code and from the microsoft graph sandbox.

Comment: I am facing the same error while looking at delta changes in calendar events. Did you able to find a solution?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use subscriptions (notification service)? We use it to get updates for room events...

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription